# If $H$ is positive definite and $A$ has full row rank, prove that $ \begin{bmatrix} H & A^T\\ A & 0\end{bmatrix} $ is nonsingular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove that $ \begin{bmatrix} H & A^T\\ A & 0\end{bmatrix} $ is nonsingular if $H$ is positive definite and $A$ has full row rank?

$H$ is $(n\times n)$ and $A$ is $(p\times n)$.

Comment: This is easy to show with the Schur complement

Answer (score 6):

Let $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^p$ be such that 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} H & A^T \\ A & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

This gives us $Hx_1 + A^Tx_2 = 0$ and $Ax_1 = 0$. Premultiplying by $x_1$ in the first equation, we get, $x_1^T H x_1 = -x_1^T A^T x_2$. Since $Ax_1 = 0$, therefore, $x_1^T H x_1 = 0$. However, $H$ is positive definite implying $x_1 = 0$ and consequently, $A^T x_2 = 0$. Since $A$ has a full row rank, the only solution to $A^T x_2 = 0$ is $x_2 =0$.  Thus, the only element in the null space of the given matrix is $0$ implying it is non singular.

Comment: Then we have $Hx_1+A^Tx_2=0$. How did you get $Hx_1=0$ and $A^Tx_2=0$ separately?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the answer accordingly. Sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
\begin{bmatrix} H & A^T \\ A & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = 0 &\iff Hx+A^Ty=0 \wedge Ax=0 \\
&\iff AH^{-1}A^Ty=0 \\
&\implies y^TAH^{-1}A^Ty=0 \\
&\iff A^Ty=0\ (H \text{ and thus }H^{-1}\text{ is positive definite}) \\
&\iff y=0 (A\text{ is of full row rank}) \\
&\implies x=-H^{-1}A^Ty =0 \implies Ax=-AH^{-1}A^Ty=0.
\end{align}
Therefore, $x=y=0$ and the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} H & A^T \\ A & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is nonsigular.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ is positive definite, so is $B = AH^{-1}A^T$. To see this note that $H^{-1}$ is positive definite, and if $u$ is such that $u^TBu = 0 \implies  (A^Tu)^T H^{-1} (A^Tu) = 0 \implies A^Tu = 0 \implies u =0$ (as A is full row rank.) So in particular $B$ is invertible.

The result now follows since the given matrix is a product of non-singular matrices:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ AH^{-1} & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} H & 0 \\ 0 & -AH^{-1}A^T\end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix} I & H^{-1}A^T \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} H & A^T \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix}. 
$$